# Microsoft Excel- prioritizing based on two date columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have two due dates I have to look out for at work, and I want to have a priority column that assigns a critical, critical,high, medium, low , low priority if either of those dates are within -120 , 5, 10, 15, 20, 120 days (respectively). Is there a way to do this while also ensuring that the formula doesn’t calculate if the cells are blank? Thanks In advance

Clarification: here is what I have so far,

```
=if(A2=“”,””,LOOKUP(A2-TODAY(),{-120,5,10,15,30,120},{“Critical”,”Critical”,”High”,”Medium”,”Low”,”Low”}))
```

But I can’t figure out how to include the dates I have in b2

I would like to know if my case load is getting close to either of the 2 expiration dates our cases have. The first expiration date is in column A2, and the second expiration date is in B2, with my priority level in C2. If I get within 30 days of either date, low priority, 15 days of either date medium priority, 10 high, 5 critical, anything past due critical. Hope I’m making sense

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Entirely possible there is a more elegant solution out there, but here's mine :).

If column A is your due date and column B is your priority:

```
 =IF(A2="","",IF(A2-TODAY()<=5,"Critical",IF(A2-TODAY()<=10,"High",IF(A2-TODAY()<=15,"Medium",IF(A2-TODAY()<=20,"Low","Low")))))
```

This is just a nested series of `IF` statements. `TODAY()` returns today's date, and subtracting it from the due date will give you the number of days difference as an integer, from which you can create said `IF` statements with strings as your output. the very first `IF` checks if the due date cell is blank, and if it is, returns a blank cell under priority.

I'm not 100% sure I understood your date criteria correctly, but you can easily change the cutoffs. For example, I'm not sure what you meant by -120 days.

Comment: `IFS()` and `LET()` can make this much shorter and - I think - easier to follow. `=LET(days,A2-TODAY(),IFS(A2="","",days<=5,"Critical",days<=10,"High",days<=15,"Medium",days<=20,"Low",TRUE,"Low"))`

Comment: -120 days would be to include any dates that are past due as a critical priority. But I have two separate expiration/due date columns, so would there be a way to do this in one formula if either column A2 or B2 have expiration dates that fall within these parameters?  This is what I have so far but I’m not sure how to include B2.

=if(A2=“”,””,LOOKUP(A2-TODAY(),{-120,5,10,15,120},{“Critical”,”Critical”,”High”,”Medium”,”Low”}))

Comment: Honestly I’d be fine with either, just stumped on how to include b2

Comment: @EngineerToast that is much better - I was not familiar with the `LET()` function. Adding that one to the arsenal!

Comment: @JuliaBacher B2 is the cell this is all typed within, meaning that B2 is where your priority, displayed as a string, will be displayed.